# Passing HTML attribute to angular js 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was trying to bind a generic attribute in angular js component. My component contains textbox what my need is I want to pass an html attribute to component template.
that is

```
<sample-component  generic-attribute="ng-class='hello'"></sample-component>
```

This is my main html component. I need to pass ng-class to my component template.

```
(function () {
        angular.module('myApp').component('sampleComponent',{
            bindings: {
                genericAttribute:'@?'
               },
            controllerAs:'ctrl',
            controller: 'sampleController',         
            template:'<input type="text"  {{ctrl.genericAttribute}} >   
            });
})();
```

Is this possible to pass whole attribute and bind it in the template.

Comment: You can pass the class inside the attribute if you want. Is there a reason why you want to pass the attribute as well?

Comment: So it will be common. That is developer can pass ng-class, id etc on same key. ie <sample-component  generic-attribute="ng-class='hello' id='test'"></sample-component>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can try is to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) in the template generation function. This should get you started:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').component('sampleComponent',{
        bindings: {
            genericAttribute:'@?'
           },
        controllerAs:'ctrl',
        controller: 'sampleController',
        template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return $compile('<input type="text"' + {{tAttrs.genericAttribute}});
        }  
        });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So I cant achieve this with string template. Can I ?

Comment: The function returns a string to `template` so the two are equivalent.

Comment: When I tried this I am getting '$compile is not defined' Error. How can I pass compile function to my template.

Comment: `$compile` can be injected, definitely in the controller but not sure about the template, it's not clear from the docs. Did you find a solution?